# Paypal IPN cant reach listener after 2 years live Help pls

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

we run a site that uses paypal with hundreds of users. its been going smooth for almost 2 years, but suddenly we started getting an email every day from paypal saying IPNs couldnt reach listener.

We checked and nothing seemed odd so i wrote paypal support and they said they couldnt help but was not affecting payments so we didndt pay much attention.

Now i see there is definetly something wrong and we are not getting the IPNs that allow our system to know if the user has paid or not, and therefor this affects to users renewing, paying but their account not being activated.

I tried Resending the IPN to get no success but not im getting 403 and 405 errors, before i had a blank space without a error number.

I dont know how to fix this and i need to fix it quick as every day we get transactions that depen on IPN to work, otherwise every day that passes its a bigger mess on our system.

Any idea how to find why is it not working if its been working for long  and well?

thanks

Comment: I see some other payments we retried are giving a 405 error and not 403

Comment: What status is your listener URL returning, if it is returning one at all? It must return an HTTP 200 status for PayPal to consider IPNs as being successfully delivered. Meanwhile, actually doing something with each IPN received is up to that listener code itself. You may need to hire a web developer if it's not something your able to debug and troubleshoot. PayPal and folks on Stackoverflow cannot do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

A listener must respond with an HTTP 200 status code for PayPal to mark an IPN as successfully received -- the lack of this is why you were receiving emails about it. Meanwhile, actually doing something with each IPN received is up to that listener code itself.

Since troubleshooting your IPN listener is what you need to do, [here is the documentation for the service](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNImplementation/), but the issue needs to be examined on your end. You can review your live account's IPN history at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history